# EF Core InMemory using SQLite DB - Foreign Key on delete behavior set null Issue

Tags: sqlite, in-memory-database, .net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.0

My .NET Core 3.1 project uses both a primary DBContext with SQL Server and also I have a secondary DBContext that is using an in-memory SQLite DB. The reason for in-memory DB is providing faster read access. My in-memory DB is setup so when ever a CRUD operation happens in SQL, the in-memory DB is updated as well.

Issue is I cannot get the ".OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull)" working on the in-memory SQLite DB. Both DBContexts and their associated Fluent API are both setup the same. I went for SQLite in-memory option on the basis that it should provide a relational DB i.e cascade delete and set null features.

In this example, I have two tables: InMemTcpServer & InMemStrings

Each InMemStrings entity has a foreign key reference to an InMemTcpServer enity (one to many relationship) therefore when an InMemTcpServer is deleted, I want the foreign key field in the InMemStrings to be set to null.

When testing this all using the DBContext from my SQL Server, this all works OK, there's something not right in the in-memory environment.

InMemStrings Model:

```
public class InMemStrings
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // Primary Key
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ConnectorType { get; set; }
    public int? TcpServerId { get; set; }
    public InMemTcpServer InMemTcpServer { get; set; }

}
```

InTcpServer Model:

```
public class InMemTcpServer
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // Primary Key
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DataFlow { get; set; }
    public string Encoding { get; set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    public int PortNumber { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public bool AutoStart { get; set; }
    public ICollection<InMemStrings> InMemStrings { get; set; }
}
```

InMemoryDbContext:

```
public class InMemDbAContext : DbContext
{
    public InMemDbAContext()
    {
    }

    public InMemDbAContext(DbContextOptions<InMemDbAContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<InMemTcpServer> InMemTcpServers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InMemImage> InMemImages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InMemSound> InMemSounds { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InMemSpeech> InMemSpeech { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InMemStrings> InMemStrings { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // If a tcpserver is deleted, set foreign key field in related Strings DB Table to null
        modelBuilder.Entity<InMemStrings>()
            .HasOne(p => p.InMemTcpServer)
            .WithMany(b => b.InMemStrings)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
    }
}
```

Method that deletes the InMemTcpServer:

```
var inMemTcpServer = _inMemDbAContext.InMemTcpServers.Where(i => i.Id == job.Id).FirstOrDefault();

if (inMemTcpServer != null)
{                                    
   _inMemDbAContext.InMemTcpServers.Remove(inMemTcpServer);
   _inMemDbAContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Once the above InMemTcpServer has been deleted, I would expect its corresponding foreign key in the other table to be set to null, just like it does in the native DBContext that is using SQL Server.

From what i've read so far, it does appear that using SQLite for an in-memory should support the use of relational tables in EF Core?